# unable to post tweet on python 3.4

Tags: python, twitter

```
import twitter

Api = twitter.api(consumer_key='[gdgfdfhgfuff] ',
                   consumer_secret='[jhhjf] ',
                    access_token_key=' [jhvhvvhjvhvhvh]',
                    access_token_secret='[hvghgvvh] ')

friends=Api.PostUpdate("First Tweet from PYTHON APP ")
```

error given

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/t7.py", line 6, in <module>
    access_token_secret='[ghfghgghv] ')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: `api` appears to be a *module*. What exact Twitter library are you using (there are at least 2 that use the `twitter` top-level package name).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
from twitter.api import Api
```

because you are importing `api` module form `twitter` package. You have to import [`Api`](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter/api.py) class from `api` module in `twitter` package.

```
....
class Api(object):
....
....
def __init__(self,
           consumer_key=None,
           consumer_secret=None,
           access_token_key=None,
           access_token_secret=None,
           input_encoding=None,
           request_headers=None,
           cache=DEFAULT_CACHE,
           shortner=None,
           base_url=None,
           stream_url=None,
           use_gzip_compression=False,
           debugHTTP=False,
           requests_timeout=None):
'''Instantiate a new twitter.Api object.

Args:
......
...
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    from twitter.api import Api
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Api'

Comment: I am using python 3.4 and twitter 1.14.2 api

Comment: As per source doe I gave in above example `api` has `Api` class. Please check code in `api` module.

Comment: You might be have different module then mine. Please check source code on net. I already gave link for module which I used.

Comment: available classes class TwitterCall(object):
class _DEFAULT
class TwitterResponse(object
class TwitterError
class TwitterHTTPError(TwitterError)
class Twitter(TwitterCall)

Comment: Yes, you have to use `Twitter` calls. This will support consumer_key attribute.

Comment: can you give me which package to install

Comment: I was refering to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-twitter/1.3.1. You can use any module. You have to understand how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can post on twitter using this sample code

```
import tweepy
consumer_key = Your_consumer_key
consumer_secret = Your_consumer_secret
access_token = Your_access_token
access_token_secret = Your_access_token_secret_key

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
single_tweet = 'hello world'
api.update_status(single_tweet)
print "successfully Updated"
```